# PHP mail function only can reply to Gmail account, but not for non-Gmail account

Tags: php, function, email

The user's message posted in my domain can be sent to my webmail, but then user is unable to receive my copy of the message that user sent to their email address. Besides that, my webmail can reply message to the user's email address, but only gmail account can received my reply in spam folder, however yahoo and hotmail account didn't receive any reply message from my webmail. At first yahoo account still can receive copy of message and reply message from webmail. But now totally can't. Can I know what's the problem? Thanks for your kindness help!

```
<?php
 session_start();
 include("functions/functions.php");
?>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $ip = getIP();

    $userName= $_POST['userName'];
    $phoneNumber= $_POST['phoneNumber'];
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $message= $_POST['message'];
    $currentdatetime=date('Y-m-d');

if(empty($userName)||empty($phoneNumber)||empty($email)||empty($message))
    {

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('All the fields must be filled in. Please try again.');";
 echo  "window.location.href='contact.php';";
 echo"</script>";
 exit();
    }

    else if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $userName)) === false) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Name must only contain letters!');";
 echo  "window.location.href='contact.php';";
 echo"</script>";
 exit();
}



    else if(strlen($phoneNumber)<11 || strlen($phoneNumber)>12|| substr($phoneNumber, 3, 1)!='-')
    {

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Phone Format is incorrect. Please use the following format: 01x-1234567');";
 echo  "window.location.href='contact.php';";
 echo"</script>";
 exit();
    }
    else if((strpos("$email","@")== 0)||  (strpos("$email",".com")== 0) )
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Email Format is incorrect.');";
 echo  "window.location.href='contact.php';";
 echo"</script>";
 exit();
 }

 else if($_POST['userName']!=''&& $_POST['phoneNumber']!='' && $_POST['email']!='' && $_POST['message']!='' ){



$to = "email@site.com"; // this is my Email address
$from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
$name = $_POST['userName'];
$contact = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
$subject = "Form submission";
$subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
$message ="Dear Sir/Madam,". "\n\n" ."New enquiry as below:" . "\n\n" ."Name:" .$name . "\n\n" . "Contact No: " . $contact. "\n\n" ."Email Address:". $from. "\n\n" ."Message/Enquiry:". $_POST['message'];
$message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers2 = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers2 .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers2 = "From:" . $to;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
echo "<script>alert('Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.')</script>";

}

//insert into databse
$insert_msg = "insert into msg(userName, phoneNumber, email, message, status, msg_date) values ('$userName', '$phoneNumber', '$email', '$message', 'Pending', '$currentdatetime')";
    $run_msg = mysqli_query($con, $insert_msg);
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body> 
  <!--start-contact-->
  <div class="contact">
    <div class="container">
    <h3>CONTACT US</h3>
    <p>Please contact us for all inquiries and purchase options.</p>

    <form action='' method='POST'>
         <input type="text" name='userName' placeholder="NAME" required>
         <input type="text" name='phoneNumber' placeholder="PHONE NUMBER" required>          
         <input class='user' name='email' type="text" placeholder="EMAIL" required><br>
         <textarea name='message' placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND">
    </form>
   </div>
   </div>
   <!--end-contact-->
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, without knowing what do we have in include("functions/functions.php");

I had a similar problem. This error can come from diverse reasons:

1) If you are using a shared server check with your provider to see if there is something that might be causing the problem or even if you have the rights to send emails, apparently you do.

2) If you are using a SMTP plugin, check that the ports 25, 587, 465, 475, and 2525 are not blocked. These ports are the ones used by hotmail and other companies to deal with emails traffic and if for some reason your script does not include these ports or for safety reasons it has blocked them, you will have problems with emails.

I suggest you to read carefully through [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)

Comment: I'm not using SMTP plugin. And not using shared server as well. Any others reason that cause this problem?

Comment: Check your server setup and see if those ports are block or not. Otherwise contact with your server provider and ask about the issue.